# Add NavLink in Google maps infowindow (React + React Router v4)

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-router-v4

I'm using Google Maps with React, React Router v4 (without any package like react-google-maps). I need to put React Router v4 component (NavLink or Link) inside infowindow. I tried to use ReactDomServer.renderToString().

```
const infoWindowContent = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <NavLink to="project/5">Show</NavLink>
        );

this.infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
```

I got solution from: [Render react-router <Link> inside google InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183312/render-react-router-link-inside-google-infowindow)

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work:

> You should not use  or withRouter() outside a < Router >

This is quite understandable, because the Router is out of range.

Do you have any ideas how fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I switched to https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react and this resolved my issue.

---

Another idea (dirty solution):

Put history in global window variable:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

if (!window.AppHistory) {
    window.AppHistory = createHistory();
}
```

In infowindow component do like this:

```
const infoWindowContent = `<a class="infowindow" onclick="AppHistory.push('/project/${id}')">Show</a>`;

this.infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
```